# Implementing interface comparators

Tags: java, comparison

Say I have a simple `interface` that I wish to be `Comparable` based on some feature:

```
interface Organism extends Comparable<Organism> {
    String getName();
    int getComplexity();

    @Override
    default int compareTo(Organism other) {
        return this.getComplexity() - other.getComplexity();
    }
}
```

Each implementing class must return a unique complexity so any two instances of a class will have the same complexity and any two instance of a different class will have a different complexity. The natural ordering will 'group' all instances of classes together.

I now want to implement this interface in a class that overrides the default comparison specifically for comparing two instance of that class within that class's group of instances in the order. I use the following pattern:

```
class Bacteria implements Organism {
    enum Shape {ROD, ROUND, SPIRAL};
    private final Shape shape;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Organism other) {
        if (other instanceof Bacteria)
            return this.shape.compareTo((Bacteria)other.shape);
        else
            return Organism.super.compareTo(other);
    }
}
```

I'm not particularly happy with this pattern of code: once the set of classes implementing the interface becomes large it becomes quite complex to maintain and requires lots of repeated code and depends on an implicit property of 'complexity'. I much prefer the `Comparator` style of defining the order. I would like to be able to implement the `Comparable` in `Bacteria` using something that looks like:

```
return Comparator
    .comparingInt(Organism::getComplexity)
    .thenComparing(Bacteria::getShape);
```

To be clear, I realise that comparators don't work like this: they are designed so that one comparator is used across a collection, not a different comparator depending on each object. I mention them here not because they are a potential solution but because the chaining style of comparators is elegant and transparent. I'm interested in whether there's a similarly elegant way to define `compareTo` to allow different orderings within a collection depending on class.

Comment: That sounds like a `Comparator` [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) to me.

Comment: Note: your type of comparison might not be transitive! Suppose `a` is a Bacteria with complexity 1, shape 2, `b` is a non-bacteria organism with complexity 2, and `c` is a Bacteria with complexity 3, shape 1. Notice that `a < b` and `b < c` and `c < a`.

Comment: I agree with @immibis.  I think that since you're not defining a valid comparison, the question isn't meaningful.

Comment: @immibis Note that I include the comment that instances of each class are equals with respect to the default comparison. All Bacteria have the same complexity as do all Tree objects etc. So I explicitly exclude your scenario.

Comment: `once the set of classes implementing the interface becomes large it becomes quite complex to maintain` - Why do you think it will become complex to maintain? Do you foresee, that the `compareTo` method of `Bacteria` would need to be changed based on other classes extending `Organism`? Or do you think it will be complex to maintain because the comparison logic for the whole hierarchy is scattered in the sub classes?

Comment: It's not a strong enough condition to say "instances of each class are equal with respect to the default comparison".  You also have to say that instances of different classes are different in this respect--or that they're equal only if they have the same type of comparison.  E.g. you _cannot_ have another class whose complexity is the same as `Bacteria` that compares some other aspect besides "shape".  Otherwise you will have a situation where compare(a,b)=0, compare(b,c)=0, but compare(a,c) != 0, which would be bad.

Comment: One other comment: IMHO `Organism` should be an abstract class, not an interface.  The reason is that you're defining something that's actually a "thing" in some sense, even though it's abstract and you can't have objects of the class without making them a more specific "thing".  An _interface_ is more appropriate when you're defining "a set of methods that you want other "things" to implement", rather than a "thing" in its own right.

Comment: @ajb I'll add a more explicit condition to the question to make it clearer: every implementation must return a different complexity. Appreciate your thoughts on interface vs. abstract class though to be honest I don't agree that `Organism` should be an abstract class. That forces all implementations to extend it even though they may be implementing other interfaces that also represent 'things'. But that's a much bigger conversation than can be carried on in the comment section!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you plan to put the `Comparator`.  Since you'd like your class to implement `Comparable<Organism>`, I'll assume you're looking for something like

```
class Bacteria implements Organism {
    enum Shape {ROD, ROUND, SPIRAL};
    private final Shape shape;

    Comparator<Organism> comparator = 
        Comparator
            .comparingInt(Organism::getComplexity)
            .thenComparing(Bacteria::shape);  // illegal

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Organism other) {
        return comparator.compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

This won't work, because `thenComparing`, in context, needs a parameter that is a `Function` that operates on an `Organism`, not a `Bacteria`.  You could work around it like this--I'll leave it to you to decide whether this is elegant enough:

```
Comparator<Organism> comparator = 
    Comparator
        .comparingInt(Organism::getComplexity)
        .thenComparing(x -> ((x instanceof Bacteria) ? ((Bacteria)x).getShape() : Shape.ROD));
```

In theory, you could also write your own method that can convert a comparator to another.  You can't use `instance.method` notation, so the use would have to be something like this:

```
Comparator<Organism> comparator = 
   MyComparatorUtilities.thenComparingIfInstanceOf(
        Comparator.comparingInt(Organism::getComplexity),
        Bacteria.class,
        Bacteria::getShape);
```

The following implementation of `thenComparingIfInstanceOf` compiles (and allows the code above to compile), but I haven't tried to test it:

```
class MyComparatorUtilities {
    public static 
    <T,U extends T,V extends Comparable<? super V>> Comparator<T> thenComparingIfInstanceOf(
        Comparator<T> comparator,
        Class<U> subclass,
        Function<? super U, ? extends V> keyExtractor) {
        return (a, b) -> {
            int comp = comparator.compare(a, b);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
            if (subclass.isInstance(a) && subclass.isInstance(b)) {
                return keyExtractor.apply(subclass.cast(a))
                    .compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(subclass.cast(b)));
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }
}
```

**MORE**: To answer the comment: no, I don't necessarily think this approach is more readable or maintainable.  In fact, I believe the whole design is unmaintainable, because it's too easy to add a class that will cause the comparison to violate the properties of a total ordering; I'd be looking for a different design, starting with a clearer definition of how I want the ordering to work on objects of different classes.  The "right" way to handle the comparisons will probably depend on that different design.

For similar problems, I might stick with a `compareTo` approach, unless I needed a class to return a `Comparator` for some other reason (e.g. there are multiple orderings defined for `Organism`s).  However, I might look for ways to eliminate duplication, if every `compareTo` is an `if` statement with the same structure, or something like that.

Comment: Do you think that this approach would be easier to maintain and/or better readable than having an `instanceof` expression in the subclass like in the original code?

Comment: @ajb Thanks for this answer. I don't necessarily disagree with you on the problem with the design - I don't like the fact that it works only through the implementations cooperating on complexity. Though I'd be interested in a view of how to achieve this elegantly: how to allow implementations of an interface to define their own ordering mechanism. I'm not sure I've seen a good example in any standard code that doesn't add a lot of unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
return Comparator
      .comparingInt(Organism::getComplexity)
      .thenComparing(o-> o instanceof Bacteria ? 
             ((Bacteria) o).getShape() : Bacteria.Shape.ROD);
```

So if it's a Bacteria, then it compares the Shapes, otherwise it compares a constant of the same type which are always equal.  If you don't use the same type in the comparison it wont compile.

This is not a generic interface but perhaps this will help others who are trying to compare properties of a limited number of subclasses.